# migration from Openldap to Samba4

Tags: migration, openldap, samba

My topic is really simple. My internship asked me to change all the backend and everything from Openldap to Samba4. They don't want to use anything from Openldap.
Without giving me the answer I'll be really thankful if somebody was able to point me in the right direction, so I can get myself into starting something... .
And if you have any question concerning what I'm suppose to do feel free to ask !!

Regards Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to directly look on the Samba Project sites: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Samba_Classic_Upgrade_%28NT4-style_domain_to_AD%29 You will also find a lot of tutorials on google.

Are there services or programs configured against OpenLDAP for registration/authentification? Please keep in mind, that this will change with Samba4 because they don't implement OpenLDAP. They are using an LDAP backend which differs from OpenLDAP (https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/FAQ#LDAP_backend).

Comment: Thanks alot, i did found everything I wanted on the Website + google !!